# Compare lines in 2 text files with different numbers of fields

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv

This is the (hopefully) final version of my script for my file comparison problem mentioned previously in two posts on Stack Overflow  ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702571/compare-lines-in-2-text-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753845/compare-lines-in-2-text-files-with-different-number-of-columns)).

I have come up with the code shown below, which does what I need it to do, but I'm wondering if it can be written in a more pythonic (read elegant) way, especially the clean up of the lists.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv

f1 = sys.argv[1]
f2 = sys.argv[2]

with open(f1) as i, open(f2) as j:
    a = csv.reader(i)
    b = csv.reader(j)
    for linea in a:
        lineb = next(b)
        lista = ([x for x in linea if len(x) > 0])
        listastr = map(str.strip, lista)
        listastrne = filter(None, listastr)
        listb = ([x for x in lineb if len(x) > 0])
        listbstr = map(str.strip, listb)
        listbstrne = filter(None, listbstr)
        if len(listastrne) != len(listbstrne):
            print('Line {}: different fields: A: {} B: {}'.format(a.line_num, listastrne, listbstrne))
        elif sorted(map(str.lower, listastrne)) != sorted(map(str.lower, listbstrne)):
            print('Line {}: {} does not match {}'.format(a.line_num, listastrne, listbstrne))
```

Example input files:

`A.csv`:

```
1,2,,
1,2,2,3,4
1,2,3,4       
X
AAA,BBB,CCC
DDD,,EEE,  
GGG,HHH,III
XXX,YYY   ,ZZZ

 k,
```

`B.csv`:

```
1,2,2,2
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4  
W
AAA,,BBB,CCC  
EEE,,DDD,,
,,GGG,III,HHH
XXX,YYY,ZZZ

,
```

Comment: I gave you an answer in Python.SE http://stackoverflow.com/a/34797098/403423

Comment: I actually saw that, thanks.  But given the fact that two people mentioned that [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is the proper place for a question like this, I decided to move it over.  My apologies if this was not proper etiquette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Less repetition

You have a lot of repeated code (and unnecessary code).  For example, you manually increment your second reader when you could zip them together.  You perform the same list comprehension on each of them.  You map multiple things onto them after a list comprehension.  You perform a pointless filter that is essentially a copy.  Removing all of this gives us this:

```
from itertools import izip
import csv
import sys


file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]    

def get_clean_line(line):
    return [entry.strip().lower() for entry in line if entry]

with open(file1) as first_file, open(file2) as second_file:
    first_reader = csv.reader(first_file)
    second_reader = csv.reader(second_file)

    for first_line, second_line in izip(first_reader, second_reader):
        first_list, second_list = get_clean_line(first_line), get_clean_line(second_line)

        if (len(first_list) != len(second_list) or 
                sorted(first_list) != sorted(second_list)):
            print('Line {}: different fields: A: {} B: {}'.format(
                first_reader.line_num, first_list, second_list))
```

You could easily move the `sorted` call into `get_clean_line` if you want to, but if you think the lengths will be different more often it might make sense to leave it there so short circuiting avoids too many expensive sorts.

#### Names

You could use better names - bytes are cheap

`file1` and `file2` vs `f1` and `f2`, `first/second_reader` vs `a` and `b`, etc.  There are probably even better names, but that would probably depend on your specific domain.

Comment: Thanks for the code, exactly what I was looking for.  I did end up changing the `if`--`or` statement back to my `if`--`elif` because I need to be able to easily check if the difference is in the number of fields or in the contents.

Comment: @MarkusHeller ah, that was my mistake, I missed that they had different error messages. Glad it could help

Answer (score 0):

## Whitespace

Your code is all far too clumped together, making it harder to read. Break things up into logical blocks so that it's easier to parse separate sets of commands. Like this:

```
with open(f1) as i, open(f2) as j:
    a = csv.reader(i)
    b = csv.reader(j)

    for linea in a:
        lineb = next(b)

        lista = ([x for x in linea if len(x) > 0])
        listastr = map(str.strip, lista)
        listastrne = filter(None, listastr)

        listb = ([x for x in lineb if len(x) > 0])
        listbstr = map(str.strip, listb)
        listbstrne = filter(None, listbstr)

        if len(listastrne) != len(listbstrne):
            print('Line {}: different fields: A: {} B: {}'.format(a.line_num, listastrne, listbstrne))

        elif sorted(map(str.lower, listastrne)) != sorted(map(str.lower, listbstrne)):
            print('Line {}: {} does not match {}'.format(a.line_num, listastrne, listbstrne))
```

This makes reading much easier and prevents the wall of text effect.

## Truthiness

You're also testing for empty strings using `len(x) > 0`, but that's inefficient when you could just use Python's truthiness. Python allows you to evaluate any type as a boolean. For strings, an empty string is `False` and a string with any characters is `True`. This, of course, fits your purposes perfectly:

```
        lista = ([x for x in linea if x])
```